# casperJS assertExists not passing on class with spaces

Tags: javascript, dom, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS, and need to select a class that contains spaces.  Did some googling but not getting what's going wrong.

HTML content :

```
<div id="member-1" class="letters vcard known"> 
 ...
</div>
```

CasperJS assertion

```
casper.test.assertExists('div.letters vcard known');
```

Also tried

```
casper.test.assertExists('div.letters\ vcard\ known');
```

Results

```
FAIL Found an element matching: div.letters vcard known
#    type: assertExists
#    subject: false
#    selector: "div.letters vcard known"
[warning] [phantom] looks you did not use begin() which is mandatory since 1.1
⚠  looks you did not use begin() which is mandatory since 1.1
FAIL AssertionError: Found an element matching: div.letters vcard known
#    type: error
#    subject: false
#    error: {"message":"Found an element matching: div.masthead vcard contact","name":"AssertionError","result":{"success":false,"type":"assertExists","standard":"Found an element matching: div.letters vcard known","file":null,"doThrow":true,"values":{"subject":false,"selector":"div.letters vcard known"},"suite":"Untitled suite in null","time":1},"line":301,"sourceId":166856896,"sourceURL":"../modules/tester.js","stack":"AssertionError: Found an element matching: div.letters vcard known\n    at assert (../modules/tester.js:301)\n    at assertExists (../modules/tester.js:493)\n    at sourceToJSON.js:41\n    at runStep (../modules/casper.js:1518)\n    at checkStep (../modules/casper.js:368)","stackArray":[{"function":"assert","sourceURL":"../modules/tester.js","line":301},{"function":"assertExists","sourceURL":"../modules/tester.js","line":493},{"sourceURL":"sourceToJSON.js","line":41},{"function":"runStep","sourceURL":"../modules/casper.js","line":1518},{"function":"checkStep","sourceURL":"../modules/casper.js","line":368}]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this :

```
casper.test.assertExists(div[class*="letters"]);
```

(if you don't have others class beginning with 'letters')

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

But i think you have three differents class so :

```
casper.test.assertExists('div.letters.vcard.known');
```

Comment: casper.test.assertExists('div.letters.vcard.known'); was successful to pass.  so I guess we replaced whitespace with periods?

Comment: In fact the name of your class is not "letters vcard known". You have three differents class on this element which are : letters, vcard and known. So to select the element by all his class, you want the div with (.letters + .vcard + .vknown) = div.letters.vcard.vknown. If your element had an id like id="idElement" too, it would have been : casper.test.assertExists('div.letters.vcard.known#idElement'); And another attribut like role="main", it would have been casper.test.assertExists('div.letters.vcard.known[role="main"]');

Comment: Thanks for the further examples